# Query dsl returning duplicate records on @one to many association(leftJoin vs leftJoin.fetch vs fetchAll)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpql, querydsl

Here is my scenario: i have person entity which looks like below.

```
@Entity     
    public class Person{
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<>(0);
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "AGENCY_ID")
        private Agency agency;
```

I am unable to retrieve correct data,when i query for persons. 
Problems i have :

```
1. duplicate records.
2. person with no agency not returning .
3. Bad performance
```

Here is what i tried, and see combination of above problems

1. `query.from(qPerson).leftJoin(qPerson.phoneNumbers, telecommNumber).leftJoin(qPerson.agency,qAgency);`

I have problem 1: which is obvious(in one-to-many relationship) and this can be solved in direct hibernate by using distinct(). I tried distinct in queryDsl and that doesnt seem to work well.

2. `query.from(qPerson).leftJoin(qPerson.phoneNumbers, telecommNumber).fetch().leftJoin(qPerson.agency,qAgency).fetch();`
   I have problem 3 in this case: returns results correctly but performance is really bad.(Cartesian product problem, i guess).
3. `query.from(qPerson).fetchAll();`

I have problem 2 in this case :This one performs well, but doesnt return person without agency when i try to sort on agency field for example. But returns that person if i dont add below to the query.

```
 query.orderBy(person.agency.agencyIdentifierDescription.asc());
```

I am trying to arrive at a solution that solves above three problems. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should define your entities as following:

"In JPA a `ManyToOne` relationship is always (well almost always) required to define a `OneToMany` relationship, the `ManyToOne` always defines the foreign key (`JoinColumn`) and the `OneToMany` must use a `mappedBy` to define its inverse `ManyToOne`."

from Wiki:

[ManyToOne](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)

[OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)

example:

```
public class Person {

    @ID
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<PhoneNumber> = phoneNumbers;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="agency_person", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="agency_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Agency agency;

    //Getters & Setters
}

//---------------------------------------------------

public class PhoneNumber {

    @ID
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="phonenumber_person", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="phone_id", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Person person;

    //Getters & Setters
}

//---------------------------------------------------

public class Agency {

    @ID
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agency")
    private Set<Person> persons;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks XiCon JFS for your answer. I tried providing @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agency")
    private Set<Person> persons; on the inverse side of the relation(Agency), and then tried fetchAll on persons, but still have problem 3 mentioned in my original question. Can you explain the importance of having @OneToMany(mappedBy) on the inverse side? These are missing in my project.

Comment: It is quite simple: If u have a bidirectional relation (as provided in my answer), you will have to declare one side as the "owning" side. Not doing so results in bad behaviour when persisting your objects. For example you save a PhoneNumber for a Person, add this PhoneNumber to the List of PhoneNumbers to the Person and save the Person... your JPA-Provider will try to persist the PhoneNumber in your Person-Object as a new PhoneNumber, although it already exists (which results in an exception or redundant data)! That is why u want to declare an owning side.

Comment: To explain it differently: If u don't define your entities as clear as possible, EclipseLink or any JPA-Provider just won't know what belongs to what, which always results in bad behavior at some point.