# Hibernate @ManyToOne and additional mapping for target's id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I saw an example of unidirectional @ManyToOne mapping with additional mapping for target's id, for example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long companyId;

    ...
}
```

I don't understand why we need additional mapping for ***companyId***. Could someone explain this trick?

Comment: Like stated before, the companyId field is not needed. But, it may be useful if you would like to access the identifier directly, without have an additional e.g. getCompany().getId() call, which may be null. To my knowledge the additional identifier field is not widely used though.

Answer (score 0):

The additional mapping for companyId is optional and depend on your business logic, not a required of JPA.
It may be good for the case when you only need to show companyId then just getCompanyId() will be faster than getCompany().getId().

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to refer to an answer of mine -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549928/5909679

First of all, your `Person`-entity and `Company`-entity need an `ID` of some sort... furthermore you can have an unidirectional `OneToMany` but a `ManyToOne` requires a bidirectional relationship.

Your field `companyId` is not needed at all and won't have any effect on your `ManyToOne`. Just the `JoinColumn` annotation is needed, which declares your desired column name in the join-table. Do it as following:

In your `Person`-entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne //FetchType.LAZY is by default
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company;
```

In your `Company`-entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<Person> persons;
```

If you want to have more control of the naming of your join-table declare it as following:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="desired_table_name", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
private Company company;
```